# Unable to Create DFS Namespace for DFS Replication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-server-2016, microsoft-distributed-file-system

First , please forgive my engrish
This could be a longshot , or nobody has ever experienced this before and I really, really need help. This might be the first time I've asked a question here

I'm trying to setup dfs replication on two servers (LIVE1 and LIVE2) in an azure subscription. This is so that when a developer uploads files to LIVE1 , it would automatically sync the files into LIVE2

dfs replication requires the servers  to be on a domain, so I added a custom domain in "azure active directory". Then I added a user "adminuser@mycustomdomain.com" (not the real user/domain) , and gave it a directory role of "global administrator"
and made it a member of group "AAD DC Administrators"

I logged in to myapps.microsoft.com and it immediately expired the password and asked for a new one. I believe it is for it to sync to the active directory.

I waited for the account to sync , then logged in as the account that i created in azure ad domain services (not as a local admin)

Also , I am unable to add the user that i created , to group "Domain Admins"

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming your using Azure AD Domain Services here? If so then it’s not going to do what you want. AAD DS does not support the creation of DFS namespaces. When you create an AAD DS Domain you are not getting domain admin rights, you are getting a specific set of rights to do things that are allowed in AAD DS, one of which is not DFS. This is the same reason why you cannot add users to the domain admin group.

If you need DFS running against domain controllers in Azure then you will need to create IaaS domain controllers.

Comment: Yes I used Azure AD Domain Services , Thank you very much for your response!